# JavaScript alert works with int but not string

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

When calling a javascript function, it only works if I pass in an int. It fails if I pass in a string.

For example, this is my controller where I'm passing in a list of people to the view.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
    people.Add(new Person() { Id = 1, FirstName = "Geddy", LastName = "Lee" });
    people.Add(new Person() { Id = 2, FirstName = "Alex", LastName = "Lifeson" });

    return View(people);
}
```

In the view, I have this javascript function:

```
function RemovePerson(firstName) {
    alert(firstName);
}
```

My webgrid has a column that allows the user to delete a person:

```
gridPeople.Column(header: "", columnName: "",
    format: (person) => MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format(
    "<a href='' onclick='RemovePerson({0}); return false;'>x</a>",
    person.FirstName))),
```

As the code is shown, above, I get this error when I click the x to delete a person:

```
Uncaught Reference Error: Geddy is not defined
```

Why?

If I change the javascript to accept an int:

```
function RemovePerson(personId) {
    alert(personId);
}
```

And actually pass the int:

```
gridPeople.Column(header: "", columnName: "",
    format: (person) => MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format(
    "<a href='' onclick='RemovePerson({0}); return false;'>x</a>",
    person.Id))),
```

It correctly shows a message box with the int value. So why does this work when passing an int but not the name?

Comment: My guess is that you need to enclose your string in quotes, otherwise your function tries to evaluate it as a variable

Comment: It often helps to post what is actually received by the client. That way errors can be fixed based on the actual output rather than interpreting the possible output from the source code.

Comment: @RobG Do you mean by posting the page source?

Comment: Yes, but just the relevant bit (e.g. the HTML for the A element), not the entire thing.

Comment: _"If I change the javascript to accept an int_ `function RemovePerson(personId){...` _"_ - Note that you haven't changed the JS to _accept_ an int: changing the name of `RemovePerson()`'s parameter from `firstName` to `personId` makes no difference. What you've changed is that you're _calling_ it with a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you need to wrap the string variable in quotes.

> Uncaught Reference Error: Geddy is not defined

That means it thinks you're referring to a variable named `Geddy` rather than the string literal `"Geddy"`.

Here's what you use:

```
string.Format("<a href='' onclick='RemovePerson(\"{0}\"); return false;'>x</a>",
person.Id)
```

Comment: That did it, but I couldn't use `""{0}""`, I had to use `\"{0}\"`.

Comment: Do you know if I should be able to actually pass the Person object to the javascript method? `function RemovePerson(person) { alert(person.FirstName); }`

Comment: @BobHorn `onclick='RemovePerson(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(person)))';`  (no need for the quotes there, because you're sending a JSON object and not a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Besides,

```
string.Format("<a href='' onclick='RemovePerson(\"{0}\"); return false;'>x</a>",
```

person.FirstName);

To be strict, use

```
person.FirstName.Replace("\"", "\\\"")
```